# Calculate the length of an array without using the length property

Tags: java

I want that as soon as my exception is raised it breaks my loop(using break function) & print i(length of array)

```
class Length{  
  static void length(String p){ 

    int i=0;
    try{
       while(i<=i){
         char ch=p.charAt(i);
         i++;
         System.out.println(ch);
    }


  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
  }

}
  public static void main(String s[]){ 

     String a=new String("jack");
     length(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: An exception thrown from your `try` block would prevent further iterations of that `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code as follows

```
static int length(String p) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while (i <= i) {
            char ch = p.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // catch specific exception
      // exception caught here
    }
    return i; // now i is the length 
}


public static void main(String s[]) {
    String a = "jack";
    System.out.println(length(a));
}
```

Out put:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanku is there any other way i can code and find length also if i don't catch exception then how can i get the length

Comment: @Jack yes there are many ways. You can count element one by one by split the String in to letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Length{  
  static void length(String p){ 

    int i=0;
    try{
       while(i<=i){
         char ch=p.charAt(i);
         i++;
         System.out.println(ch);
    }


  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("String length is  : + " i)
    // System.out.println(e);
  }

}
  public static void main(String s[]){ 

     String a=new String("jack");
     length(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the `length()` you calculate, and you could use the for-each operator on the `String` by iterating the `char`(s) from [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) with something like

```
static int length(String p){ 
    if (p == null) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : p.toCharArray()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following application to find out the length of a word

```
public class Length {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Length().length("Jack");

}

private void length(String word){
    int i = 0;
    char []arr = word.toCharArray();
    for(char c : arr){
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Length of the "+ word+ " is "+ i);
}
```

}